# multiple columns to single datetime dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains (among others) columns for the time of day (00:00-23:59:59) day (1-7), month (1-12), and year (2000-2019). How can I combine the values of each of these columns on a row by row basis into a new DateTime object and then store these new date-times in a new column? I've read other posts pertaining to such a task but they all seem to involve one date column to one DateTime column whereas I have 4 columns that need to be transformed into DateTime. Any help is appreciated!

e.g.

```
| 4:30:59 | 1 | 1 | 2000 | TO 200/1/1 4:30:59
```

this is the only code I have so far which probably doesn't do anything

```py
#creating datetime object (MISC)
data = pd.read_csv('road_accidents_data_clean.csv',delimiter=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
n = 0
df['datetime'] = data.loc[n,'Crash_Day'],data.loc[n,'Crash_Month'],data.loc[n,'Year']
```

My DataFrame is layed out as follows:

```
Index | Age | Year | Crash_Month | Crash_Day | Crash_Time | Road_User | Gender | 
  0      37   2000         1            1        4:30:59     DRIVER      MALE
  1      42   2000         1            1        7:45:10     DRIVER      MALE
  2      25   2000         1            1        10:15:30   PEDESTRIAN  FEMALE

Crash_Type | Injury_Severity | Crash_LGA | Crash_Area_Type | Datetime |
  UNKNOWN          1              YARRA      MELBOURNE          NaN
 OVERTAKING        1              YARRA      MELBOURNE          NaN
ADJACENT DIR       0              MONASH     MELBOURNE          NaN
```

NOTE: the dataframe is 13 columns wide i just couldn't fit them all on one line so Crash_Type starts to the right of Gender.

below is the code i've been suggested to use/my adaptation of it

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Crash_Time=['4:30:59','4:20:00'],
    Crash_Day=[1,20],
    Crash_Month=[1,4],
    Year=[2000,2020],

))


data['Datetime'] = df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(
    np.sum([
        df['Year'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['Crash_Month'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['Crash_Day'].astype(str),
        ' ',
        df['Crash_Time'],
    ]),
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
```

I've adapted this code in order to combine the values for the datetime column with the my original dataframe.

Comment: I could show you how to read in the csv using `.read_csv(...., parse_dates={...})`, but you don't have much example data to try some things out...

Answer (score 1):

Combine the columns into a single series of stings using `+` (converting to `str` where needed with `pandas.Series.astype` method) then pass that new series into `pd.to_datetime` before assigning it to a new column in your df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=['4:30:59'],date=[1],month=[1],year=[2000]))

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['year'].astype(str)+'-'+df['month'].astype(str)+'-'+df['date'].astype(str)+' '+df['time'],
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
print(df)
```

[example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28time%3D%5B'4%3A30%3A59'%5D,date%3D%5B1%5D,month%3D%5B1%5D,year%3D%5B2000%5D%29%29%0A%20%0Adf%5B'datetime'%5D%3Dpd.to_datetime%28%0A%20%20%20%20df%5B'year'%5D.astype%28str%29%2B'-'%2Bdf%5B'month'%5D.astype%28str%29%2B'-'%2Bdf%5B'date'%5D.astype%28str%29%2B'%20'%2Bdf%5B'time'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20format%20%3D%20'%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S',%0A%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=2&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

edit: You can also use a `numpy.sum` to make that one long line adding columns together easier on the eyes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    time=['4:30:59','4:20:00'],
    date=[1,20],
    month=[1,4],
    year=[2000,2020],

))

df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(
    np.sum([
        df['year'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['month'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['date'].astype(str),
        ' ',
        df['time'],
    ]),
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
```

[sum example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20time%3D%5B'4%3A30%3A59','4%3A20%3A00'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20date%3D%5B1,20%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20month%3D%5B1,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20year%3D%5B2000,2020%5D,%0A%0A%29%29%0A%20%0Adf%5B'datetime'%5D%3Dpd.to_datetime%28%0A%20%20%20%20np.sum%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'year'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'month'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'date'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%20',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'time'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%29,%0A%20%20%20%20format%20%3D%20'%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S',%0A%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

edit 2: Using your actual column names, it should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
'''
Index | Age | Year | Crash_Month | Crash_Day | Crash_Time | Road_User | Gender | 
  0      37   2000         1            1        4:30:59     DRIVER      MALE

Crash_Type | Injury_Severity | Crash_LGA | Crash_Area_Type | Datetime |
  UNKNOWN          1              YARRA      MELBOURNE          NaN
'''
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Crash_Time=['4:30:59','4:20:00'],
    Crash_Day=[1,20],
    Crash_Month=[1,4],
    Year=[2000,2020],

))

df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(
    np.sum([
        df['Year'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['Crash_Month'].astype(str),
        '-',
        df['Crash_Day'].astype(str),
        ' ',
        df['Crash_Time'],
    ]),
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
print(df)
```

[another python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0Aimport%20numpy%20as%20np%0A'''%0AIndex%20%7C%20Age%20%7C%20Year%20%7C%20Crash_Month%20%7C%20Crash_Day%20%7C%20Crash_Time%20%7C%20Road_User%20%7C%20Gender%20%7C%20%0A%20%200%20%20%20%20%20%2037%20%20%202000%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204%3A30%3A59%20%20%20%20%20DRIVER%20%20%20%20%20%20MALE%0A%0ACrash_Type%20%7C%20Injury_Severity%20%7C%20Crash_LGA%20%7C%20Crash_Area_Type%20%7C%20Datetime%20%7C%0A%20%20UNKNOWN%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20YARRA%20%20%20%20%20%20MELBOURNE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NaN%0A'''%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Crash_Time%3D%5B'4%3A30%3A59','4%3A20%3A00'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Crash_Day%3D%5B1,20%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Crash_Month%3D%5B1,4%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Year%3D%5B2000,2020%5D,%0A%0A%29%29%0A%20%0Adf%5B'Datetime'%5D%3Dpd.to_datetime%28%0A%20%20%20%20np.sum%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'Year'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'Crash_Month'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'-',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'Crash_Day'%5D.astype%28str%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%20',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'Crash_Time'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%29,%0A%20%20%20%20format%20%3D%20'%25Y-%25m-%25d%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S',%0A%29%0Aprint%28df%29%0A&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

One thing to note is that you might want to double check if your csv file is separated by just a comma or could it be a comma and a space? possible that you may need to load the data with `df = pd.read_csv('road_accidents_data_clean.csv',sep=', ')` if there is an extra space separating the data in addition to the comma. You don't want to have that extra space in your data.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! What do i need to do to iterate this code over each row of my dataframe? like do i need to assign each variable as 'n' and then let n = the row number or something to fill in the values for each row of the new column?

Comment: Nothing. It will apply this logic to all rows. See the example I edited in with a second row in the df.

Comment: The code returned NaN in all rows of the datetime column- what's the fix for this? Also will this code return the date/time combination for each row of the dataframe without having to enter them manually into the year, month,day,time columns? i have 115k lines so that's not practical. Thanks!

Comment: when you print the df after loading the csv file what does it look like? did you change the column names from what I had in my example to match the actual column names of your `df`? unrelated but you don't need to do `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`, you can just do `df = pd.read_csv('road_accidents_data_clean.csv',delimiter=',')` since `pd.read_csv` will return a `pandas.DataFrame` object anyways. You may need to update your question with a new code example that shows how you are trying to implement my suggestion.

Comment: after i execute the code the dataframe loads in as normal except with the new datetime column on the far right-hand side. The datetime column just has NaN for every value from row 0 to row 115k

Comment: Yeah. I would need to see what this source data looks like and how you are implementing my suggestion to help you debug this. You can see from the python tutor links in my answer that this should work, you just would likely need to change the names of the columns from my example to match the names they actually have in your df.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that- alternatively, I could show you the source file if that'd help- or at least do a .head() type thing to show you the first 4-5 lines?

Comment: Yeah if you could edit the post with a link to the source csv or an image of it or even what the df looks like when you print the head. That might help a lot.

Comment: I've edited my original question to include the first line(s) of my dataframe- i couldn't figure out how to convert the PNG to a URL so i've just recreated it.

Comment: I updated my answer using your column names. Also might want to double check if maybe the csv is separated with a comma and a space not just a comma.

Comment: I've added a version of your code which combines the datetime column with my original dataframe-  the first two rows contain the right datetime contain the values which have been entered by the code however the rest of the rows contain 'NaT'. Also how can i fill the datetime column using the code you've provided automatically? because thus far we've just been entering the values automatically whereas id like to get the code to do this automatically. Thanks!

Comment: That should just work for all the rows in your `df` weather it's just one or a million. if you are getting `NaT` values for all but the first two rows after running that one line then something must wrong with with the the values of those columns that you are constructing the data from. could be extra white space in the string for the time, which is really hard to notice.  You could try to remove the `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',` argument. from the call of `pd.to_datetime` pandas is pretty good at figuring out the format automatically.  Also crash time is in 24hour time correct?

Comment: Okay- i'll give that a try and get back to you and yes Crash_Time is in formatted as 24hr time.

Comment: I haven't yet managed to get that working- are there any other ways in which I could get a full list of date-times from my data frame? I'm under a bit of a time crunch right now.

Comment: is there anyway you can share your csv file like on a google drive or something? I feel like I could figure this out if I just had access to your source data, but without that I don't know if I can be of much more help here.

Comment: sure- i can send you the file, how should i do that?